# React object state not persisting while calling in multiple functions

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to change the state of allImageData in handleImage function and in convertImagetoBlob function. The problem is that the state is being set in convertImagetoBlob() but not in handleImage(). The key photo is being empty after calling convertImagetoBlob() but other keys in allImageData are being set fine.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

P.S if this code can be written in a better way, Please share your view.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Compressor from "compressorjs";
import { motion } from "framer-motion/dist/framer-motion";

const UploadImage = () => {
const [allImageData, setAllImageData] = useState({
    photo: {},
    error: "",
    blobImage: "",
    compressImage: {},
});

const validFileTypes = ["image/jpeg", "image/png"];

const compressImage = (photo) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        new Compressor(photo, {
            quality: 0.6,

            success(result) {
                resolve(result);
            },
            error(err) {
                console.log(err.message);
                reject(err);
            },
        });
    });
};

const convertImageToBlob = (file) => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var url = reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
        console.log("url", url);
        //it is being set here.
        setAllImageData({
            ...allImageData,
            error: "",
            compressImage: file,
            blobImage: reader.result,
        });
    };
};

const handleImage = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    console.log("e", e);
    const file = e.target.files[0];

    if (file && validFileTypes.includes(file.type)) {
        //why photo state is not being set here.
        setAllImageData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, photo: file }));
        compressImage(file)
            .then((res) => convertImageToBlob(res))
            .catch((err) => console.log("err", err));
    } else {
        setAllImageData({
            ...allImageData,
            photo: "",
            error: "Please upload a valid Image type(jpeg/png)",
        });
    }
};

const variants = {
    hidden: { opacity: 0 },
    visible: { opacity: 1 },
};

return (
    <form encType="multipart/form-data" className="form_upload">
        {!allImageData.blobImage && (
            <>
                <input
                    type="file"
                    id="actual-btn"
                    hidden
                    onChange={handleImage}
                />
                <motion.div
                    variants={variants}
                    initial="hidden"
                    animate="visible"
                    className="text_abs"
                >
                    Choose File
                </motion.div>
                <motion.label
                    variants={variants}
                    initial="hidden"
                    animate="visible"
                    className="btn_upload"
                    style={{ marginTop: "-2rem" }}
                    htmlFor="actual-btn"
                ></motion.label>
            </>
        )}

        {allImageData.blobImage && (
            <motion.div
                variants={variants}
                initial="hidden"
                animate="visible"
                className="imageOptions"
            >
                <button
                    onClick={(e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        console.log("uploading to DB");
                    }}
                    style={{ marginTop: "-2rem" }}
                    className="btn_upload"
                >
                    Upload
                </button>
                <div className="showImageBlob">
                    <img src={allImageData.blobImage} />
                </div>

                <button
                    style={{ marginTop: "-2rem" }}
                    onClick={() =>
                        setAllImageData({
                            photo: {},
                            error: "",
                            blobImage: "",
                            compressImage: {},
                        })
                    }
                    className="btn_upload"
                >
                    Cancel Upload
                </button>
            </motion.div>
        )}
    </form>
);
};

export default UploadImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is modified code that should work for you ([Run Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/upload-image-test-z7j55?file=/src/UploadImage.js)). I comment your problematic  line and pass the file in parameter of `convertImageToBlob` function. I update the state for both **res** and **file** object inside of the function `convertImageToBlob`.

Previous code was not updating the photo because `useState` takes sometime to update the state. Here you update the state with photo and after you update the state again inside of the function `convertImageToBlob` where you replace all previous data using `...allImageData`. By that time your first update of state might not finish yet. so photo was still blank.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Compressor from "compressorjs";
import { motion } from "framer-motion/dist/framer-motion";

const UploadImage = () => {
  const [allImageData, setAllImageData] = useState({
    photo: {},
    error: "",
    blobImage: "",
    compressImage: {}
  });

  const validFileTypes = ["image/jpeg", "image/png"];

  const compressImage = (photo) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      new Compressor(photo, {
        quality: 0.6,

        success(result) {
          resolve(result);
        },
        error(err) {
          console.log(err.message);
          reject(err);
        }
      });
    });
  };

  const convertImageToBlob = (file, res) => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var url = reader.readAsDataURL(res);

    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
      console.log("url", url);
      //it is being set here.
      setAllImageData({
        ...allImageData,
        error: "",
        photo: file,
        compressImage: res,
        blobImage: reader.result
      });
    };
  };

  const handleImage = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    console.log("e", e);
    const file = e.target.files[0];

    if (file && validFileTypes.includes(file.type)) {
      //why photo state is not being set here.
      //setAllImageData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, photo: file }));

      compressImage(file)
        .then((res) => convertImageToBlob(file, res))
        .catch((err) => console.log("err", err));
    } else {
      setAllImageData({
        ...allImageData,
        photo: "",
        error: "Please upload a valid Image type(jpeg/png)"
      });
    }
  };

  const variants = {
    hidden: { opacity: 0 },
    visible: { opacity: 1 }
  };

  return (
    <form encType="multipart/form-data" className="form_upload">
      {!allImageData.blobImage && (
        <>
          <input type="file" id="actual-btn" onChange={handleImage} />
          <motion.div
            variants={variants}
            initial="hidden"
            animate="visible"
            className="text_abs"
          >
            Choose File
          </motion.div>
          <motion.label
            variants={variants}
            initial="hidden"
            animate="visible"
            className="btn_upload"
            style={{ marginTop: "-2rem" }}
            htmlFor="actual-btn"
          ></motion.label>
        </>
      )}

      {allImageData.blobImage && (
        <motion.div
          variants={variants}
          initial="hidden"
          animate="visible"
          className="imageOptions"
        >
          <button
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();

              console.log(allImageData, "all111");
              console.log("uploading to DB");
            }}
            style={{ marginTop: "-2rem" }}
            className="btn_upload"
          >
            Upload
          </button>
          <div className="showImageBlob">
            <img src={allImageData.blobImage} alt="" />
          </div>

          <button
            style={{ marginTop: "-2rem" }}
            onClick={() =>
              setAllImageData({
                photo: {},
                error: "",
                blobImage: "",
                compressImage: {}
              })
            }
            className="btn_upload"
          >
            Cancel Upload
          </button>
        </motion.div>
      )}
    </form>
  );
};

export default UploadImage;
```